# Using "then" in this context

Tags: writing, academic-writing

As a non-native learner, Our 10-line essay on *daily routine* is full of the word **then.**

> I get up at 6 o clock in the morning. **Then** I make my bed and go to the bathroom.
>   **Then** I have breakfast with my family around 8:30. **Then** I leave home at 9:30.

Blah.. blah blah..

Please tell me about the cases where I should and shouldn't use **then**.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Well, you can remove most of them and reword the sentences a bit. But then it won't be question of "should" or "should not" (which implies rules or guidelines), but of style and idiomatic usage. Also, do you mean 10-sentence?

Comment: *I get up at 6 a.m., make my bed, and go to the bathroom. I have breakfast with my family around 8.30. I leave the house at 9.30. It takes me three and a half hours to leave the house every morning. I wish I could just bring it with me, and live my life like a snail.*

Comment: @userr2684291 Yaaayyy. Right on the money there. I like the snail reference. :)

Comment: It sounds awkward repeating the same adverb over and over again. If you really did want to heavily emphasise the passage of time without repetition you could use other standard English sequencers such as "First", "Next", "After that", "Finally"  etc.

Answer (score 1):

It's just a matter of style: sounds a bit dramatic with *multiple* 'then', like it does in the famous Doors song, The End:

> *He went into the room where his sister lived, and **then** he*
>   
> *Paid a visit to his brother, and **then** he 
> He walked on down*
>   *the hall, and 
> And he came to a door 
> And he looked inside...*

As for *your* text, you can safely remove the *second* instance of *then* (you even specify the exact time after it) and replace the *third* one with '*and*' (omitting 'I' after it) - to join the last two sentences.